# How to make api call with optional payload in React JS

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-functional-component, payload

I am trying to call API in React JS with AXIOS. I need to send payload as optional when productID has value.

```
    This is my service.js file
    
fetchProducts: (payload) => put(`/products`, payload),
fetchProductsProductID: (params, payload) => put(`/products`, payload, { params }),

products.js

       useEffect(() => {
            if (productID) {
                CommonSrv.fetchProductsProductID(
                    { productID: productID },
                    {
                        data: data,
                    },
                )
                    .then((resp) => {
                       console.log(resp)
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err)                  
                      });
            } else {
                CommonSrv.fetchProducts({ data: data })
                .then((resp) => {
                    console.log(resp)
                 })
                 .catch((err) => {
                     console.log(err)                  
                   });
            }
        }, [])
```

within the then and catch blocks same conditions I need to use. Because of productID, I am duplicating my code a lot how can I simply this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that!

```js
(productID ? 
   CommonSrv.fetchProductsProductID(
      { productID: productID },
      {
         data: data,
       },
    )
    : 
    CommonSrv.fetchProducts({ data: data }))
).then(.....).catch(...)
```